# Is it possible to create a realm db without a cloud instance?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

All of the documentation that Ive seen for realm, specifically for react native, wants me to use a sync'd realm that is hosted on their cloud platform. The information is "stored locally" but is there any way to set this up without using their cloud service?

Comment: Yes. Realm is a local-first, online second database. So by nature, data is stored locally. See the [Realm React Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass "sync" property to the configuration, you can see all available props [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#%7EConfiguration)

```
const dbRealmConfig = {
  schema: [model1, model2]  
}

const localRealm = await Realm.open(dbRealmConfig);
// or if you need synchronously -> new Realm(dbRealmConfig);

// do whatever you want with the realm
const [grabSomeObject] = localRealm.objects('model1').filtered(`SomeModelProp = "${someVariable}"`);
localRealm.write(() => {
  someVariable.SomeModelProp = 'abc';
...
});
```

You should go through the Realm docs Jay linked ([Realm React Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#installation)), it's pretty well explained.